# Variable no se almacena en PHP desde HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Buenas Tardes Estimados Compañeros, mi problema es el siguiente, tengo dos archivos `.HTML` y `.PHP` ya que mando a llamar una variable desde `input` en `html` y `post` para `PHP` dejo ambos archivos, ya que mando a llamar la variable para ejecutar una sentencia `SQL`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="asistencia.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value=""/>
         <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

y el codigo en `php` es:

```
<?php
$server     = 'localhost'; //servidor
$username   = 'root'; //usuario de la base de datos
$password   = ''; //password del usuario de la base de datos
$database   = 'gym'; //nombre de la base de datos

$conn = @new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) //verificamos si hubo un error al conectar, recuerden que pusimos el @ para evitarlo
{
    die('Error de conexión: ' . $conn->connect_error); //si hay un error termina la aplicación y mostramos el error
}
  @$bookid = $_POST['id'];
   @$mostrar=$_POST['mostrar'];

   if($mostrar){
       $sql="select * FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente = '$bookid' ";
       $rsql= mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die (mysql_error());
       $sw=0;
   }

   /************Formulario*****************/
   echo"<form action=asistencia.php method=POST>";
   echo "<table id='tabla3'> <tr>";
       echo "<th>idPagoCliente</th>";
       echo "<th>idCliente</th>";
       echo "<th>idTipoperiodo</th>";
       echo "<th>inicio</th>";
       echo"<input type=submit name=mostrar value=Obtener Datos>";//Pulsa el boton para "generar tabla"
   echo "</tr>";
   echo"</table>";
   echo"</form>";
   if(@$sw>0){
       echo "<table id='tabla4'>";
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rsql)){
            echo"<tr>";
               echo "<td>";
                   echo $row['idPagoCliente'];
               echo "</td>";
               echo "<td>" ;
                   echo $row['idCliente'];
               echo "</td>";
               echo "<td>";
                   echo $row['idTipoPeriodo'];
               echo "</td>";
               echo "<td>";
                   echo $row['inicio'];
               echo "</td>";
               echo "<td>";
                   echo $row['final'];
               echo "</td>";
               echo "<td>";
                   echo $row['costo'];
               echo "</td>";
           echo"</tr>";
       }
       echo"</table>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Estimado esto no tomará valor: `$_POST['mostrar']` porque en el formulario no hay ningún elemento con el `name="mostrar"`, y si ese valor es fundamental para la ejecución no puede estar vacío. Lo que hay en `$_POST` es un array asociativo de todos los elementos del formulario, cuya clave es el valor de `name` y el valor el dato que haya en el elemento. Para ver lo que hay en tu post puedes hacer algo como `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Estimado el valor que necesito es el  @$bookid = $_POST['id']; , el valor mostrar funciona correctamente ya que ejecuto la consulta con una palabra constante. en otro archivo los mando a llamar bien, pero casualmente en este no.

Comment: Aquí o falta código o se está mostrando otra cosa. No es posible que haya dato en `$_POST['mostrar']` en un escenario como el que indicas. Prueba a poner el `if`  de este modo a ver qué pasa: `if($bookid){`  y dinos si hiciste un `var_dump($_POST);` y que muestra en pantalla dicho var_dump.

Comment: Busca en el archivo PHP ya que el mostrar esta a en Submit en la septima fila al comienzo del formulario para tabla.

Comment: echo"<input type=submit name=mostrar value=Obtener Datos>";

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, la propiedad **'value'** del input está vacía, quizá ese sea el problema. Mira, lo tienes así:

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" value=""/>
```

Por lo que en la consulta SQL, el **@$bookid = $_POST['id'];** va a estar vacío y nunca hará la consulta.

Pienso que eso podría ser.

Comment: Hola Fernando, que debería poner en Value?

Comment: Deberías poner el id o el número que vas a comparar en el where: $sql="select * FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente = '$variableQueContieneElValue' ";

Comment: Intenta colocar en el value un id que ya tengas en la Base de Datos para que al compruebes si te retorna algo la consulta.